# .cur Image Converting Software

Tags: css, cursor, image-conversion

I have an transparent .PNG image that I need to convert into an .CUR file. Does anyone know of good online software for converting .CUR or free-inexpensive downloadable softare?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this question doesn't belong here. maybe superuser.com

Comment: While I agree, cursors and icons are something programmers often need...

Comment: My client wants the cursor over certain images to change to a magnifying glass to imply zoom to the visitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try AniFX at <strike>http://icofx.ro/anifx/index.html</strike>, they also provide an icon creator called IcoFX.

**Update:**

According to the [site forum](http://icofx.ro/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=88), AniFX has been combined into IcoFX:

> Mon Feb 27, 2012 11:04 am
>
> The last version of the freeware AniFX was released on 18 Nov 2008.
>
> AniFX was merged in the meantime into IcoFX. Since version 2.0 IcoFX supports also cursor editing with all the features of AniFX integrated.

So the link above may no longer work, but the main site still does:

- http://icofx.ro/

Comment: The original site is broken, but it appears someone has recently made it portable: http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/anifx_portable

Answer (score 3):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php), it is free and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Greenfish Icon Editor Pro worked for me (got it here: http://greenfish-icon-editor-pro.en.softonic.com/download)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.graphic-converter.net/mac-graphic-converter.htm

Converts images into .cur files and works on macs. 30 day free trial.